# Parsing Text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, text

I'm attempting to parse a text string with jQuery and to make a variable out of it. The string is below:

```
Publications Deadlines:   armadllo
```

I'm trying to just get everything past "Publications Deadlines:   ", so it includes whatever the name is, regardless of how long or how many words it is.

I'm getting the text via a the jQuery .text() function like so:

```
$('.label_im_getting').text()
```

I feel like this may be a simple solution that I just can't put together. Traditional JS is fine as well if it's more efficient than JQ!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cHU86/2/)**

**First part**

```
str = $.trim($('.label_im_getting').text().split(':')[0]);
```

**Second part**

```
str = $.trim($('.label_im_getting').text().split(':')[1]);
```

Comment: Perfect! The only thing was that I wanted the second half of the split, so (using @alex23 's response), I switched the index to get the second half. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
var string = input.split(':') // splits in two halfs based on the position of ':'
string = input[1] // take the second half
string = string.replace(/ /g, ''); // removes all the spaces.
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and awesome response! I choose @Adil 's solution as it utilizes jQuery more, but this answer gives me the background to what is actually happening behind the scenes and how to manipulate it. Thank you!